# How to detect keyboard animation end in Android? or instantly hide keyboard without animation

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I have many `EditText` that I set some of those to `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)` and let our Input View to handle the insert data.

But some of them, I use original Keyboard from `EditText`.

When I touch normal `EditText` normal Keyboard show up and from this state when I touch my custom `EditText` normal Keyboard doesn't hide instantly and my custom input show above that Keyboard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add following method to your activity in which you want to hide your in-built `SoftKeyBoard`.

   ```
   public void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
       InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
   }
   ```
2. Now in `onCreate` add following lines after `setContentView()`.

   ```
   final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTitle);
   editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
           android.util.Log.i(TAG, "Touch");
           hideSoftKeyboard(JoinImageActivity.this);
           //Open your custom keyboard here
           return true;
       }
   });
   ```

Here you can open your custom keyboard as it hides the in-built one. I hope this can help you out.

Comment: This doesn't disable hiding animation. @Sizer did it really helped?

Comment: @elf_zwölf This is working code. Kindly check your code properly may it contain devil inside somewhere which prevents the `Keyboard` to get hide.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you ues your own keyboard layout ?

Or if you want to use then you have to change it in to its style.

here is the code of the default KeyboardView style:

```
<style name="Widget.KeyboardView" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/keyboard_background</item>
    <item name="android:keyBackground">@android:drawable/btn_keyboard_key</item>
    <item name="android:keyTextSize">22sp</item>
    <item name="android:keyTextColor">#FFFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:keyPreviewLayout">@android:layout/keyboard_key_preview</item>
    <item name="android:keyPreviewOffset">-12dip</item>
    <item name="android:keyPreviewHeight">80dip</item>
    <item name="android:labelTextSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:popupLayout">@android:layout/keyboard_popup_keyboard</item>
    <item name="android:verticalCorrection">-10dip</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#BB000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2.75</item>
</style>
```

Hope you get understand.

Feel free for comments.